Car rental in US-- liability insurance as a standalone? (don't have a car, do have credit card insurance)
I've got a question about liability insurance when renting cars in the US. I don't have a car so don't have car insurance, and use my Chase Sapphire Reserve as primary insurance. But I just discovered that it doesn't cover liability, which I believe is a requirement in most if not all states (and probably is a sensible thing to have).
I've tried to search for this but am failing, any recommendations for how to avoid having to pay the $15/day+ at the rental counter? There was a question here a decade ago, but the solutions don't work for me, unfortunately.
Although I'm currently living overseas, I am a US citizen with a US license, and maintain a US address, so if there's some sort of basic policy I could get, I can do that. I can't get a car rental quote in the UK because I don't have a UK license (I know people who have done that with US licenses, and then car rental place wouldn't honor the rate as it was for UK drivers).

I searched liability insurance to rent a car in usa and got a long list of potential providers
